# Use same name for class member and constructor parameter

Tags: c++, constructor

Say I have a class with a constructor as follows.

```
// C++
class Person
{
    int age;
    Person(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }
};
```

Is there a way to use `age` instead of `a` in the constructor's attribute? It would make the code easier to read. In Python I can do it with:

```py
# Python
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age)
        self.age = age
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should use the member initializer list to initialize members. This list is a special case where there is no ambiguity between a member and a parameters name and there is no shadowing:

```
class Person
{
    int age;
    Person(int age) : age(age) {}
                //   member(parameter) 
}
```

Whether you rely on this or you apply a naming scheme that distinguishes parameters from members is a matter of style and there are good arguments for either.

For more details on constructors and the member initializer list I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think the equivalent to your Python example would be:

```
Person(int age)
{
    this->age = age;
}
```

Agree that it's advisable to use the member initializer list, but `this->` works also in functions other than the constructor, so it's good to at least know about it:

```
void set_age(int age)
{
    this->age = age;
}
```